Interpretation of first and second moments of Risk Neutral Densities for AMD
Suppose I have correctly computed the option-implied risk neutral density for AMD options expiring in exactly 1 week, and discounted this expectation with the correct risk free rate, using the Breden Litzenberger result. Let us pretend that these AMD options, while American are basically equivalent for European Options.
Now suppose I calculate the following moments:
(1) Expected-value over the entire density. Sum(f(Xi)*Xi)/N for all i=1...N
(2) Transform the X axis (strikes) into a return by computing (K-s0)/S0. Then compute the standard deviation over the entire return density (volatility).
I would like to check if my intuition is correct regarding these statistics.
(1) This gives the forward price of AMD under the risk neutral measure. When I do this calculation, the expected value is very close to current trading price.
(2) This gives me the volatility of the return distribution under the risk neutral measure. It turns out to be around 3%. However, most amd options of this maturity have IV of 50% or higher. Why is there such a large discrepancy?


yes, forward from risk free rate (which is negligible for such short periods). 2) have you annualized and not daily vol? ~3%*sqrt(365) is ~50. Be careful with the interpretation of that data. Any probabilistic statements derived from options are only valid in the risk-neutral world.


By Breeden-Litzenberger you have a discrete estimate of $p(S_T = K)$. You can now calculate the expected variance as $-\frac{2}{T}e^{-rT} \int_0^\infty \ln (K/S_0) p(S_T = K) dK$ where $S_0$ is the current spot price. The square root of this expected variance should be not too far off the ATM IV.

Ok thank you so much. I didn't annualize the volatility, now everything is consistent.!
